# Transitioning opacity and visibility

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have an element that is `visibility: hidden` until hovered over, with a transition on the opacity for a nice fade. The problem is that fade only works one way, because when the element instantly becomes `visibility: hidden` which hides the opacity transition. How can I work around this?

Edit: To be clear, it is important that the element have `visibility: hidden` until the hover is activated. An element with `opacity: 0` can be interacted with, while an element with `visibility: hidden` cannot.

Example below. Notice how the popup fades in, but not out.

```css
.hover {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.label {
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.popup {
  width: 90px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s;
}

.hover:hover .popup {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">
  <div class="label">Hover me</div>
  <div class="popup">I am only visible on hover</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only applied `transition` on `opacity`, if you need the `transition` works several properties you have to use `all` or use property names.

Just change below css part

```
.popup {
  width: 90px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 3s; /*Change the opacity to all*/
}
```

```css
.hover {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.label {
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.popup {
  width: 90px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 3s; /*Change the opacity to all*/
}

.hover:hover .popup {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">
  <div class="label">Hover me</div>
  <div class="popup">I am only visible on hover</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not know you could animate visibility. Thanks. (To avoid transitioning other properties, `transition: opacity 3s, visibility 3s;`)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `visibility:hidden;` in `.popup` class since you won't see it anyway when its opacity is 0.

I don't actually know what exactly your case is. If this is not what you're looking for, please explain more specifically.

---

I have updated the code to meet your case. I use `display: none` instead of `visibility:hidden` and insert a simple Jquery code.

In my opinion, it should be nice if you make the `.popup` visible on clicking `.label`, instead of hovering it. The Jquery code for that should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".label").click(function(){
        $(".popup").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".label").mouseover(function(){
   $(".popup").stop().slideDown("slow");
  });
  $(".popup").mouseout(function(){
   $(".popup").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.hover {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.label {
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.popup {
  width: 90px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  display: none;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 3s;
}

/*.hover:hover .popup {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover">
  <div class="label">Hover me</div>
  <div class="popup">I am only visible on hover</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `visibility: hidden` is not the same as `opacity: 0`. You can still click on and otherwise interact with an `opacity: 0` element, but this is not the case with `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: In that case I think you should use Jquery. I'll update the snippet above.