# Why is a transition applied to opacity if there's no transition on visibility?

Tags: css

Given the following snippet:

```js
setInterval( function() {
  $( 'div' ).toggleClass( 'hide show' );
}, 2000 );
```

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  width: 100px;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide"></div>
```

I wouldn't expect to see the transition on `opacity` since the `visibility` has no transition, and I assumed would take effect immediately. However, **when `.show` is applied to my `div`, I see the transition**. When `.hide` is applied, it disappears immediately (as I'd expect).

Why?

Comment: Seems very related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916376/transitioning-opacity-and-visibility

Comment: @j08691 you're right. The answer to this question is in the second sentence of that question, doh :|

Comment: Close as a dupe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`visibility` does take effect immediately. When you apply `hide` the element is immediately hidden so you can't see it. When you apply `show`, the element is immediately "visible" but with an opacity of 0, so you still can't see it. After that, the opacity transition occurs.

What is the intended behavior you are expecting? Or was this just a question out of curiosity?

Comment: Ah of course, that makes perfect sense. It was purely out of curiosity (:

Answer (score 1):

the `transition` indeed doesn't work on `visibility` as also on `display`.
but if you add `transition` to both in and out selectors you'll get `opacity` fade both ways

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('div').toggleClass('hide show');
}, 2000);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  width: 100px;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 2s;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show"></div>
```